# Replacing 1 laptop monitor with another

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure

I have 2 laptops, both are not working.

- 1 has a problem with the monitor (it shows the initial boot screen, but doesn't show windows)
- the second has a working monitor but a problem somewhere else

Is it possible to simply replace the bad monitor with the working 1. They're different brands (HP and Gateway). I've opened both laptops before and I can see they're connected at 2 places (1 location near the power button, and 1 location on the back with 2 wires, 1 black and 1 white wires).

So is it possible to disconnect these wires from 1 laptop and connect it to the other?

Comment: Do you mean swap the LCD screens, not "monitors"? A little clarity on the issue please.

Comment: Boot off a Linux/WinPE live CD before considering the first LCD to be bad.  A bad LCD will show defects at the initial BIOS screen.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bad monitor if it still shows the boot screen? Also, I would do some research to make sure the two panels used in those 2 models are compatible. Even if they're the same size and resolution, they could have different connectors, different power requirements, different mounting positions, different thickness, etc.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx I mean the part of the laptop that opens up and closes. The entire top half of the laptop.

Comment: @ultrasawblade I see, so what could be the problem in your opinion?

Comment: Yea it may be a tough go, alot of things have to match up like both have the same voltage requirements, same connectors, same resolution, same mounting hardware, etc... The other LCD may power on with the other laptop but it may not fit or mount like the original did.

Comment: If a Linux live CD works in your laptop, then something is wrong with your Windows install and you should try reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "boot screen" (really the bios UI), then your laptop's LCD screen is good (the monitor).
Either someone has toggled the optional video out (the option to display video exclusively on an external monitor or tv) or some windows video driver is misconfigured (assuming you are using windows).
Most laptops have a some special keyboard key combination to toggle between : laptop display, external video or both. There is probably an icon that looks like a tv screen beneath this key.
If the problem is the windows driver, try hitting f8 a few times as soon as you see the "boot screen". If lucky, you'll get a windows boot menu with the option "safe boot". That option uses the default video driver/settings.
As far as switching LCD's between two different laptop makers - its very unlikely they are plug compatible. Also the plan to just switch the top is probably not hardware feasible.(hindges/sockets/screws unlikely to fit)